# How to add a record to a database using Qwik and Prisma?

Tags: crud, prisma, qwik

1. You have to define a loader in the index.tsx file, outside of the component and export it:

```js
export const useAddProduct = routeLoader$(async () => {
return await prisma.products.create({ 
    data: {
      name: 'Steel Table',
      description: 'A steel table added to DB'
    }
})
```

2. You call this loader from inside your component:

```js
const handleSubmit = $(() => {useAddProduct()})
```

My problem is **how to tell the loader about the data object**, since no parameters are accepted?
When fetching by id I could use params:

```js
export const useProductById = routeLoader$(async ({ params }) => {
  if (params.id) {
    const id = parseInt(params.id)
    return await prisma.products.findUnique({ 
      where: { id }
    })
  }
  return []  
});
```

Are there similar contexts apart from { url, method, params } I should know of?

Every hint in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In qwikcity if you want to submit form data and mutate any data on the server you have two options:-

- `routeAction$` or `globalAction$`
- `server$`

`routeAction$` is scoped in a route and `globalAction$` is globally available. If you are doing same form handling from different different route then go for `globalAction$`.

```js
export const useAddProduct = routeAction$(
  async (data, { redirect }) => {
    await prisma.products.create({
      data,
    });

    throw redirect(STATUS_CODE,URL)
  },
  
  zod$({
    name: z.string(),
    description: z.string(),
  })
);
```

`zod$` and `z` are imported from `@builder.io/qwik-city`. after submit your data call `redirect` so that your active route loader will call and new data will display.

Next you can handle form action

```js
const addProductAction= useAddProduct();

<Form action={addProductAction}>
    <div>
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>

     <div>
       <label for="description">Description</label>
       <input type="text" name="description" id="description" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</Form>
```

`server$` is another option to run code on the server

```js
const addProduct = server$((name: string, description: string) => {
  return await prisma.products.create({
    data: {
      name,
      description,
    },
  });
});
```

and then call `addProduct` and pass `name` , `description` just like a normal function call with parameters

```js
        <button
          onClick$={async () => {
            const product = await addProduct(
              name, // from signal
              description // from signal
            );
             console.log(product)
          }} 
        >
          Create
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my static Qwik app, I use a function

```
export const addCustomer = server$(async (data) => {...
```

to perform some task in my MongoDB when click in a Btn

```
<button onClick$={async () => {const resume = await addCustomer(customerRecord); ...}
```

, and everything works fine in development environment. So I pushed changes to production in Vercel host. Then when I send the information again it Fails giving me this error in browser console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure.
```

HELP!